# Problems on running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have tried to install gem draper and it asked me to update my activerecord to version 3.2.6. Done it I have installed succesfully draper but now when running my web application with rails server it gives me this error:

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': **You have already activated multi_json 1.3.6
, but your Gemfile requires multi_json 1.3.5. Using bundle exec may solve this.**

I use aptana studio 3

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have run `bundle update` after changing your Gemfile.

Then you need to do what the error message says and use `bundle exec`, which uses the gems from your Gemfile.lock, rather than the gems installed on your server.

So run this:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Comment: Please update your answer with you Gemfile then. Have you run `bundle update`?

Answer (score 0):

please try to run :

```
bundle install
```